# Excel lookup if matching key and another value in the same row is greater than 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of keys that I want to return another key if another column matches that key and is greater than one. Then it will return the key if that same other column is equal to 1. I will attempt to explain this better with visuals below. I would appreciate any assistance or at least how I would go about doing this.

What I am Starting With:

[image]

What I would like to end with:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the "quantity" column is doing/how it should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$9)/($A$2:$A$9=$E2),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

Put that in the first cell and copy over as far as desired and down the unique list:

[image]

---

If one has Office 365 Excel then put this in the first cell and drag down the unique list and it will spill to the right as needed:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E2,""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pivot table` and put Key1 in the rows and Key 2 in the columns. Then you can drag the Quantity fields into the filter and make sure you only get the columns = 1.
Finally, if you want to initial Key for the quantity that is > 1 you could either use a second pivot or you order die initial table descending by quantity and use `index match` or `vlookup` to return the first match (which if ordered correctly will be the key for the quantity > 1).

Comment: A pivot table will not return what the op wants.  Power pivot will but not the standard pivot table.